# I have below test code. How can I made this condition to be True

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below test code.  How can I made this condition to be True.  I know a.split is method in Str() but when I put it on a variable it sees it as a list.

```
a="1.1.1.1/29"

aa=a.split('/')

>>aa == "29"

>>False
```

Comment: use `print(aa)` to see what you have in variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use in on the list like

```
a="1.1.1.1/29"

aa=a.split('/')

>>"29" in aa

>>True
```

Answer (score 0):

Split does indeed splits a string into substring and returns the resulting substrings inside a list.

Below condition returns True:

```
aa[1] == "29"
```

Answer (score 0):

[str.split](http://%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) gives you a list, and so does `a.split('/')`,  and if you compare a list to a string, it will obviously fail

You need to take the last element of the list and compare that to `29` for the code to work as follows.

```
In [119]: a="1.1.1.1/29"                                                                                                                                                          

In [120]: aa=a.split('/')                                                                                                                                                         
#Gives you a string
In [121]: aa                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[121]: ['1.1.1.1', '29']
#Second element of list is 29, comparison returns True
In [122]: aa[1] == '29'                                                                                                                                                           
Out[122]: True
#List to string comparison returns False
In [123]: aa == '29'                                                                                                                                                              
Out[123]: False
```

But you can check membership using the `in` operator, to see if the item is contained in the string itself, which will save you the hassle of splitting the string and comparison the item of the list

```
In [125]: a="1.1.1.1/29"                                                                                                                                                          

In [126]: '29' in a                                                                                                                                                               
Out[126]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.split()` returns the "list of strings after splitting the original by the delimiter you specified.

```
a = '1.1.1.1/29'
aa = a.split('/') # aa is now ['1.1.1.1', '29']
subnet = aa[1] # subnet is '29'
```

You can learn more about it here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split

Comment: sorry. forgot to include the index.  But this will do too.